# Oracle database column ambiguously defined / invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I've tried to write a SQL statement to select from some tables. But when I run it, I get an error, and I don't know how to fix it.

When I just select from `vertrag` and join `pgrdat`, `abrkreis`, `mandant` and `komm_dat`, everything works fine.

However, when I try to add `literal` into the joins, I get the following error:

> ORA-00904: "VERTRAG"."MAN" invalid identifier
>   on (left join literal on literal.lit_kzl = pgrdat.beruftit and literal.man = vertrag.man)

or

> ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
>   on (left join Literal on Literal.LIT_KZL=pgrdat.BERUFTIT and Literal.man=man)

`literal.man` and `vertrag.man` both exist.

Here's my SQL:

```
SELECT man,
       ak,
       pnr,
       vertrag.vertnr,
       vertrag.eintrt2,
       vertrag.ma_ab,
       vertrag.verbegin,
       vertrag.ver_ab,
       vertrag.ver_bis,
       vertrag.verende,
       vertrag.enlogru,
       pgrdat.spr,
       pgrdat.anrede,
       pgrdat.auswnr,
       pgrdat.beruftit,
       pgrdat.daschudat,
       pgrdat.fax,
       pgrdat.gebdat,
       pgrdat.gebname,
       pgrdat.gebort,
       pgrdat.geschl,
       pgrdat.lnd,
       pgrdat.miname,
       pgrdat.namevor,
       pgrdat.namezus,
       pgrdat.naname,
       pgrdat.ort,
       pgrdat.plz,
       pgrdat.plzfach,
       pgrdat.postfach,
       pgrdat.pst_ab,
       pgrdat.pst_bis,
       pgrdat.staat,
       pgrdat.staat2,
       pgrdat.strasse,
       pgrdat.telgesch,
       pgrdat.telprivat,
       pgrdat.titel,
       pgrdat.vorname,
       pgrdat.empfaenger,
       pgrdat.taetint,
       pgrdat.zimmer,
       pgrdat.sachbegrp,
       pgrdat.logasach,
       pgrdat.stellung,
       pgrdat.logasach2,
       pgrdat.sachbegrp2,
       abrkreis.ak_bez,
       abrkreis.ak_kurz,
       abrkreis.ak_ort,
       abrkreis.ak_plz,
       abrkreis.ak_fax,
       abrkreis.ak_plzfach,
       abrkreis.ak_postfach,
       abrkreis.ak_strasse,
       abrkreis.ak_telefon,
       abrkreis.ak_text,
       mandant.man_bez,
       mandant.man_fax,
       mandant.man_firma,
       mandant.man_kurz,
       mandant.man_ort,
       mandant.man_plzfach,
       mandant.man_plzstr,
       mandant.man_postfach,
       mandant.man_st_nr,
       mandant.man_strasse,
       mandant.man_telefon,
       komm_dat.km_art,
       komm_dat.km_ab,
       komm_dat.km_bis,
       komm_dat.km_bem,
       literal.lit_txt
FROM   vertrag
JOIN   pgrdat
USING  (man, ak, pnr)
JOIN   abrkreis
USING  (man, ak)
JOIN   mandant
USING  (man)
LEFT   JOIN komm_dat
USING  (man, ak, pnr)
LEFT   JOIN literal
ON     literal.lit_kzl = pgrdat.beruftit
AND    literal.man = man
WHERE  superman IN ('41900', '41901', '41902', '41903')
AND    literal.lit_art = 'BERUFTIT'
AND    ver_ab <= trunc(SYSDATE)
AND    pgrdat.pst_ab <= trunc(SYSDATE)
AND    ((ver_bis >= trunc(SYSDATE) AND pgrdat.pst_bis >= trunc(SYSDATE)) OR (ver_bis IS NULL AND pgrdat.pst_bis IS NULL));
```

Comment: you have to explicitly tell from which table the column `man` in the join condition  `and Literal.man=man` is as there are probably in several

Comment: when i write
"left join literal on literal.lit_kzl = pgrdat.beruftit and literal.man = vertrag.man"
ORA-00904: "VERTRAG"."MAN" invalid identifier apperas

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with mixing `using` and `on` join syntax. There is a third variant you didn't try:

```
left join Literal on Literal.LIT_KZL=pgrdat.BERUFTIT and Literal.man=komm_dat.man
```

which gets

```
ORA-25154: column part of USING clause cannot have qualifier
```

You can't use the unqualified `man` because it's ambiguous (appearing in several tables); you can't use a qualifier because it's been used in earlier `using()` clauses.

If it was an inner join you could change that `Literal` join to `using (man)` and move the `lit_kzl` check to the `where` clause, but as it's an outer join that won't work (or at least, would force it back to being an inner join).

You probably need to change all the other `using` clauses to `on`, unfortunately:

```
...
from vertrag
join pgrdat on pgrdat.man = vertrag.man and pgrdat.ak = vertrag.ak and pgrdat.pnr = vertrag.pnr
join abrkreis on abrkreis.man = vertrag.man and abrkreis.ak = vertrag.ak
join mandant on mandant.man = vertrag.man
left join komm_dat on komm_dat.man = vertrag.man and komm_dat.ak = vertrag.ak and komm_dat.pnr = vertrag.pnr
left join Literal on Literal.LIT_KZL=pgrdat.BERUFTIT and Literal.man=vertrag.man
and Literal.LIT_ART='BERUFTIT'
where ...
```

I've moved `and Literal.LIT_ART='BERUFTIT'` from the `where` clause into the join condition, as that would also have forced that outer join to become an inner join again.

Comment: now i get: ORA-00904: "VERTAG"."MAN": invalid identifier on line:   
join pgrdat on vertag.man=pgrdat.man and vertrag.ak = pgrdat.ak and vertrag.pnr=pgrdat.pnr

Comment: That's because it should be `vertrag.man`, and not `vertag.man` ?